# CSV file formatting

Tags: php, csv, ms-access, export-to-csv

I have problem: I need to be able to import CSV file to MS Access database with PHP. I have a script that can do it, but my CSV file format is not right.

The original format is:
[image: Original format]

But the script works with this format: 
[image: needed format]

Both files are .csv. How can I convert the first file format to the needed one?

My import script below is not importing anything, and is not giving any errors:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $i=0;
            require "connection.php";
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
                echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
            }
            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
            $import=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
                    dateandtime,
                    lastname,
                    firstname,
                    paidtime,
                    approvedtime,
                    notadhering)VALUES(
                    ?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000,"\t","'")) !== FALSE) {
                if($i>0) {
                $data = str_replace('"', '', $data);
                $myDate =  date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data[0])));
                $import->bindParam(1, $myDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(2, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(3, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(4, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(5, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(6, $data[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                str_replace('"',' ',$data);
                $import->execute();
                }
                $i++;

            }
```

**EDIT Current code:**

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $i=0;
            require "connection.php";
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
                echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
            }
            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
            $import=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
                    dateandtime,
                    lastname,
                    firstname,
                    paidtime,
                    approvedtime,
                    notadhering)VALUES(
                    ?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $badlines=[];
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000,"\t",'"')) !== FALSE) {
    if($i>0) {
        //skip but keep track of bad data
        if(count($data) !== 5){
            $badlines[] = $i;
            continue;
        }
        $myDate =  date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data[0])));
        $names = explode(',', $data[1]);
        $import->bindParam(1, $myDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(2, $names[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(3, $names[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(4, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(5, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(6, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->execute();
    }
    $i++;

}
            $removal=$db->prepare("delete FROM adherence WHERE approvedtime = '0' OR notadhering IS NULL");
            $removal->execute();

            fclose($handle);
        }
```

Comment: The first one is tab delimited. If using `fgetcsv()` then just change the third param to `"\t"`.

Comment: replacing commas with tab (\t) might help

Comment: or replacing `,` with a tab in the import code

Comment: Need to see your code to help

Comment: Code: while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000,'\t',"'")) !== FALSE) {
Gives error: Notice: fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a single character

Comment: Not importing anything, and does not give any errors.
Import script: in Edit

Comment: I dont see how this could have ever worked - `str_replace` accepts a string but is beings passed an array

Comment: Replacing "\t" in fgetcsv to ','   -  makes it work with comma delimited files. Is it possible to replace tab delimiters to comma delimiters when reading file?

Comment: Oh OK, i see why it worked with commas - you where relying on a bug! i'll write an answer

Comment: On a bug? Wow, now I feel even more lost on this one

Comment: @Steve "If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed with every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well." https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"name, lastname"` is a single column, as it is surrounded by double quotes. 
Your code originally worked as you misconfigured fgetscsv by passing a single quote as the enclosure parameter, causing it to ignore these double quotes and treat the single column as two as it contains a comma.

As your new file is tab delimetered, it does not split on the comma.

To fix, pass the correct enclosure parameter to fgetcsv, and split the column yourself:

```
$badlines=[];
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000,"\t",'"')) !== FALSE) {
    if($i>0) {
        //skip but keep track of bad data
        if(count($data) !== 5){
            $badlines[] = $i;
            continue;
        }
        $myDate =  date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data[0])));
        $names = explode(',', $data[1]);
        $import->bindParam(1, $myDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(2, $names[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(3, $names[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(4, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(5, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->bindParam(6, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $import->execute();
    }
    $i++;

}
```

Comment: Error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 
Line: $names = explode(',', $data[1]);

Comment: @JustinasT Then those are not tabs after all - its hard to tell with a screenshot. Though you would have had the same error with your existing code

Comment: File format is: File.csv.
When opened with text editor - it looks like in screenshot.
When opened in excel - it looks like regular excel file, each tab in separate cell (A-date, B-lastname,name, C-Other data etc.).

Comment: No idea how to check it?

Comment: Can you just open in text editor, copy say the 1st 10 lines and paste it to pastebin? Or is the data confidential?

Comment: Does it help to figure this out?

Comment: Well it works up until line 6 is hit, because that doesnt contain a 5th column

Comment: lines 6 and 12 in the csv you posted to pastebin do not contain as much data as the others

Comment: Maybe there is a way to simply skip these fields?

Comment: There certainly is, how would you like to do it? Skip the whole row? Or add null/empty string in place of the field?

Comment: All I wish this application to start importing data, rows that has less information - entire row should be skipped.

Comment: @JustinasT OK, i made an edit. Note that `$badlines` will contain a list all the skipped lines if you need to check them manually

Comment: Import fails. It is importing only date values to database, which are all the same: 1970/01/01

Comment: Yeah my physic powers are clearly not up to scratch here. The sample data you provided works with the code above. Beyond that i have no way of helping any further. Good luck